# How to format a particular datetime field in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, view, odoo-8, datetime-format

I want to display and make selectable a particular datetime field in 12 hour format in  Odoo 8. Generically, it is done by: **Settings > Translations > Languages > Edit > Time Format**, but I want to do it for a single datetime field on some form view.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a QWeb view or an XML view?

Comment: It is an xml view. i know how to do that in qweb view.

Comment: You can use a workaround by creating a dependent field, which computes the time in a certain format and on the view, you can use that field.
Doing this you will have to also take note of the values going during creation and updating of the record.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you have some options:

- **Solution 0, easy**. Convert the datetime field in the `write` or `create` orm method. For example if `25/11/2017 16:41:51` is inserted in the field, you sould convert it to `25/11/2017 4:41:51`. That's what Odoo makes by default for the 12 hour format.
- **Solution 1, easy**. Change the field to choose only the date like this:

  ```xml
  <field name="date" widget="date"/>
  ```

  And you can create another field to set the time:

  ```py
  time = fields.Float(
      string='Time'
  )
  ```

  You can use the `float_time` widget to show the time format in the form:

  ```xml
  <field name="time" widget="float_time" />
  ```

  You can also do the validation or the conversion in the `write` or `create` method if you want.
- **Solution 2, difficult**. You can create a new widget or you can change the slider of the datetimepicker, the JavaScript function is in the file `/addons_path/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`

  ```
  $.extend(Timepicker.prototype, {

      // [...]

      _injectTimePicker: function() {

          // [...]

          this.hour_slider = $tp.find('#ui_tpicker_hour_'+ dp_id).slider({
              orientation: "horizontal",
              value: this.hour,
              min: o.hourMin,
              max: hourMax,       // this is the value to change
              step: o.stepHour,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                  tp_inst.hour_slider.slider( "option", "value", ui.value);
                  tp_inst._onTimeChange();
              }
          });
  ```

  You also must override the validation, I think there is no easy way to find it. You may do this validation in the `write` and `create` mehtod as well to make it easier.